# Is it possible to set default state for Gooey checkbox widget?

Tags: python, argparse

I have agrparse + Gooey program, and I'm adding the feature to load default settings from the config file. Everything works as expected, except the checkboxes (store_true, store_false, store_const). If I set the default=True for param with action="store_true", this argument will always be True no matter whether checkbox checked or unchecked. This is kind of logical from the perspective of agrparse (as I need to skip the argument to get False value), but a bit wrong from the perspective of the gui app.

Is there a way to create a checkbox widget, set default state to it (I can't hardcode it because it's loaded from the config file) and then pass the correct argument value depending on the checkbox state, that is possibly changed by user?

Here's small test program I created to demonstrate the issue.

```
import argparse
from gooey import Gooey

@Gooey
def main():

    config = {
        "save_settings": True, 

        # "store_false_param": True,
        # "true_checkbox_param": True,
        # "false_checkbox_param": False,
        # ... some other settings
        }
    # config = conf_obj.load_settings()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--save_settings", default=config['save_settings'], action="store_true", help="Save app settings")

    # parser.add_argument("--store_false_param", default=config['store_false_param'], action="store_false", help="store_false param")
    # parser.add_argument("--true_checkbox_param", default=config['true_checkbox_param'], action="store_const", const=True, help="checkbox param = True")
    # parser.add_argument("--false_checkbox_param", default=config['false_checkbox_param'], action="store_const", const=True, help="checkbox param = False")

    # some other arguments


    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("args.save_settings", args.save_settings)

    # print("args.store_false_param", args.store_false_param)
    # print("args.true_checkbox_param", args.true_checkbox_param)
    # print("args.false_checkbox_param", args.false_checkbox_param)
    


main()
```

it prints `args.save_settings True` no matter if checkbox checked or unchecked.

I would expect that `store_const` to work the way I expect, but this is not the case. It's also always sets arg to True if default is True.

I tried to experiment with GooeyParser but has no luck.

I ended up with workaround replacing checkbox with choice=["Yes", "No"], it works but it's kind of lame. I'd like to use checkboxes for these options.

Another workaround I came up with is to switch store_true with store_false depending on default value and then analyze the result comparing it with default value, but that's even worse.